# midpoint circle algorithm isn't outputting anything?

Tags: javascript, html, geometry

Okay so I'm new to html and javascript right now. My task is to draw circles, I have looked at countless examples and my code doesn't draw anything. Here is what I have so far.

```
<script id="vertex-shader" type="x-shader/x-vertex">
attribute vec4 vPos;

void main()
{
  gl_PointSize = 10.0;
  gl_Position = vPos;
}
</script>

<script id="fragment-shader" type="x-shader/x-fragment">
precision mediump float;
uniform vec4 u_color;

void main() {
    gl_FragColor = u_color;
}
</script>


<script type="text/javascript" src="webgl-utils.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="initshaders.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="lines.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
var canvas;
var gl;

window.onload = init;

function init() {
 canvas = document.getElementById("gl-canvas");
gl = WebGLUtils.setupWebGL(canvas);
if (!gl) {
    alert("WebGL isn't available");
  }

 var program = initShaders(gl, "vertex-shader", "fragment-shader");

 var vPos = gl.getAttribLocation(program, "vPos");
 var colorUniformLocation = gl.getUniformLocation(program, "u_color");
var buffer = gl.createBuffer();
 gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer);



  gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(vertices), gl.STATIC_DRAW);

  gl.viewport(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  gl.clearColor(0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 1.0);
  gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

  gl.useProgram(program);
  gl.enableVertexAttribArray(vPos);
  gl.vertexAttribPointer(vPos, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

  var red = 0.0;
  var green = 0.0;
  var blue = 1.0;

var vertices = circle(100,100,200);

 for (var i=0; i<vertices.length; i++)
 {
   gl.uniform4f(colorUniformLocation, red, green, blue, 1.0);
   gl.drawArrays(gl.POINTS, i, 1);
  }
  }
     </script>

  <body>
   <canvas id="gl-canvas" width="1000" height="1000">
     Oops... your browser doesn't support HTML5's Canvas elements!
   </canvas>
   </body>
   </html>
```

The error seems to happen at var vertices = circle(100,100,200);

My circle function looks like this.

```
function getPoints(x,y)
  {
  var points = [];  
  points.push(x+x0,y+y0);
  points.push(-x+x0,y+y0);
  points.push(x+x0,-y+y0);
  points.push(-x+x0,-y+y0);
  points.push(y+y0,x+x0);
  points.push(-y+y0,x+x0);
  points.push(y+y0,-x+x0);
  points.push(-y+y0,-x+x0);
  return points;
  }
function circle(x0, y0, radius)
{
      var vertices = [];
      var points = [];
      var pk = 1- radius;
      var xk = radius;
      var yk = 0;
    //var pk = ((xk +1)^2) + ((yk -.5)^2) - (radius^2);
 points = getPoints(x0,y0);
 for(var i = 0 ; i < points.length; i++)
     {
     vertices.push(points[i]);
     }

while(xk>yk)
{
    yk++;
    if(pk <0)
    {
    points = getPoints(xk+1,yk);

    pk = pk + (2* yk)+1;
    }
    else
    {
    points = getPoints(xk+1,yk-1);

    xk--;
    pk = pk + (2* yk) -(2* xk)+1;
    }
    for(var i = 0 ; i < points.length; i++)
    {
    vertices.push(points[i]);
    }

}
return vertices;
}
```

From what I can tell the algorithm is correct, but for some reason the var vertices isn't returning correctly, because when I launch the file it draws the background but the circle is nowhere to be seen. Please help!

UPDATE
So I have fixed one problem, but my program is still not printing anything out. my circle function now looks like this.

```
 function drawCircle(x0, y0, radius)
{
       var vertices = [];

       var pk = 1- radius;
       var xk = 0;
       var yk = radius;


  //vertices.push(100,100);     I am using these for error checking
  //vertices.push(200,100);     To see if vertices returns anything at all
  //vertices.push(300,100);     and from what i can tell it doesnt.
  //vertices.push(400,100);

  while(xk<yk)
  {
      xk++;
      if(pk <0)
      {
      pk = pk + (2* xk)+1;
      }
      else
      {
      yk--;
      pk = pk + (2* xk) -(2* yk)+1;
      }
      vertices.push(x+x0,y+y0);   //This should be adding all symmetric 
      vertices.push(-x+x0,y+y0);   //points from the first one around the 
      vertices.push(x+x0,-y+y0);    //circle
      vertices.push(-x+x0,-y+y0);
      vertices.push(y+y0,x+x0);
      vertices.push(-y+y0,x+x0);
      vertices.push(y+y0,-x+x0);
      vertices.push(-y+y0,-x+x0);

  }
 return vertices;
 }
```

Comment: What errors do you see in the console?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. All i have done for this class is write the code then open it up in chrome andsee what picture i have drawn.

Comment: Chrome has a developer console (press f-12). In there you have a javascript console tab which will show you any errors that javascript is throwing. If you are going to do web development, make the dev tools one of your best friends.

Comment: Okay yes I get this error.   [.Offscreen-For-WebGL-0805BD30]GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_OPERATION : glDrawArrays: attempt to access out of range vertices in attribute 0. So its saying that there are no verticies in my array? as in an out of bounds error at array position 1?

Comment: Okay hold up. Just wanted to say you are a god. I didnt know f-12 existed, but now it all makes sense. Thank you so god damn  much

Comment: Glad it helps :) Like I said, make it one of your best friends. As to your error - I am not a WebGL person so I can't help much further.

Comment: Alright Thanks though, i have narrowed down the issue to something with the gl.drawArrays